# How to pass request headers in HTML object tag?

Tags: javascript, html, session-cookies, setcookie

I am trying to embed HTML page from a web application in my website using object tag. Both website and the web application's HTML page are hosted in same domain. I am trying to pass cookie information(basically jsessionid) from my website to the web application's HTML page. I tried with embedding it in url, but the information is not getting passed. Is there any alternative to achieve this or i am doing it in wrong way? Kindly direct me to the right way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set arbitrary HTTP headers when requesting content using an `<object>`.

The only time you can add HTTP headers is when using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` but in those cases the cookie headers are protected and you cannot set them.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this?